# Tensorflow running slow on iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, tensorflow

I am running the [camera iOS example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/ios_examples/camera) distributed by tensorflow, and it is quite slow: 4-5 seconds per inference on an iPhone6, running the [inception5h.zip](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip) model.

To my understanding, this is GoogleNet model, which is light-weighted, and the iOS code pulls its first output layer, which is about half of size of the full model. I ran the same model with the python interface on my macbook, which takes 30 ms per inference.

So I am wondering why it is about 150x slower running the same model on iOS than on macbook. Seems I'm doing some obvious things wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't well-documented yet, but you need to pass in optimization flags to the compile script to get a fast version of the library. Here's an example:

`tensorflow/contrib/makefile/compile_ios_tensorflow.sh "-Os"`

That should bring your speed up a lot, informally I see a second or less with GoogLeNet on a 5S.

Comment: In build_all_ios.sh, there's this line # Build the iOS TensorFlow libraries.
tensorflow/contrib/makefile/compile_ios_tensorflow.sh "-O3". Your flag is "-Os", is this a typo?

Comment: -O3 is better for both speed and size. Also, build_all_ios.sh already passes in -O3 to the compile_ios_tensorflow.sh call